# HTML Form submits empty (yes I have names) C#

Tags: c#, html, forms, post

Using C# with Razor syntax

I cannot figure out what is wrong...

I have a simple HTML form (I'm going to convert it to HTML Helpers soon). I have a form and within the form I have two `<select>` elements that contain names. For some reason the data is posting, but without any parameters

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="~/modules/parts/bom_ervd.cshtml">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>Unit Size<span class="req">*</span></label>
                <select class="form-control isReq" name="ervd_unitsize" id="sel_ervd_custom_unitsize">
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="101" disabled>Box 1 (1,500 to 3,000CFM)</option>
                    <option value="102">Box 2 (2,000 to 4,800CFM)</option>
                    <option value="103">Box 3 (3,500 to 7,500CFM)</option>
                    <option value="104">Box 4 (5,000 to 10,000CFM)</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>Power<span class="req">*</span></label>
                <select class="form-control isReq" name="ervd_power" id="sel_ervd_custom_power">
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="208/3/60" data-val="7" data-typ="0">208/3/60</option>
                    <option value="230/3/60" data-val="12" data-typ="0">230/3/60</option>
                    <option value="460/3/60" data-val="20" data-typ="1">460/3/60</option>
                    <option value="575/3/60" data-val="23" disabled>575/3/60</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>

    </div>

    <div id="form_subcomponents">

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <hr class="hr1" style="margin-top:40px !important;" />
            <input class="btn-block btn btn-info" type="submit" id="btn_ervd_custom_submit" value="Submit"/>
        </div>

    </div><!-- end form sub components-->

</div><!-- end row -->
</form><!-- end form -->
```

Here's the code for page:  **bom_ervd.cshtml**

```
@{
    if (isPost) {
        if (Request.Form["ervd_unitsize"] == null) {

            /* this is what I'm seeing */
            <p>I'm getting null values</p>  

        }

        else {

            <p>The value is: @Request.Form["ervd_unitsize"].ToString()</p>

        }

    }
    else {
       <p>No Data posted!</p>
    }

}
```

In this scenario I ensure I select an option that has a value

I have also tried `Request["ervd_unitsize"]` and still get `null` values

Why is it Posting but getting null values?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you see in the actual HTTP POST request?

Comment: I'm assuming you select something before clicking the submit button, yes?

Comment: John, yes I select something (I also said that in my post)

Comment: @trailmax,  I get directed to that page "bom_ervd" and I see text "I'm getting null values"

Comment: Weird thing. I just used jquery Ajax to post the data (I didn't serialize the form, I passed both variables) and it posted the data properly.

Comment: @bagofmilk what I meant is to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect the POST request and see what is submitted to your endpoint. I suspect you are not submitting what you think should be coming through.